# Change product label Magento

Tags: magento, templates, product, label, php

I'm trying to change product label on my site.
The new products have a label 'Novos' I need to change it to 'novo'. It looks like this:

| (NOVOS)        |
| product image  |
| Price          |

My phtml file is calling $helper->getProductLabel($_product) to show this labels. I'm a noob so I have no idea where I can change it

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

just check the $helper will be defined somewhere in page.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('custommodule/helpername');
```

in that helper getProductLabel($_product) method will be present.